# What does >0.3 do in a model.predict statement?

Tags: python, input, keras, deep-learning, predict

I came across the following `model.predict` format of code in fitting 2 layers of input to the RNN model. This is performed in keras.

```
y_pred = (model.predict(x=[X_test_pad, X_test_psl])>0.3).astype(np.int32)
```

I am quite new to deep learning models and am not familiar with the format where we specify `>0.3`, or any value for the inputs. Hence, I'd like to know what exactly the `>0.3` does in this case.

Any clarification in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: To make sure that `y_pred` always have more than `0.3` predicted by your model. It's like  `series > your value`

Comment: @shaikmoeed So, does it imply that any value predicted to be less than 0.3 will be disregarded during the prediction? or are they disregarded as false during the evaluation for the performance index metrics such as test accuracy?

Comment: Yes, right. `series > your value` this gives you a true, false series. which converted to `int`. Something like this, `>>> np.array([True,False]).astype('int32')

==> array([1, 0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The >0.3 is not part of the model.predict function. 
The result of the prediction is compared with a decision threshold of 0.3.

Example: 
Tumor detection in brain images

If your model says that it is 40% sure that I have a tumor, I will not home happily just because 0.4 < 0.5 --> no tumor.

Instead I will want to use a decision threshold with which I will compare the model result. In this case we want all output that the model associates with a 30% chance to be considered as a positive.

You can write is as:

```
model_pred = model.predict(x=[X_test_pad, X_test_psl]
y_pred = (model_pred>0.3).astype(np.int32)
```

For more information, I recommend to read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/classification-probability-threshold

Comment: Thank you so much for this comprehensive clarification. I would just like to know if it's advisable to involve a decision threshold in a deep learning model that should ideally find the patterns and predict the target value (bool) based on the input provided? Because, different users can come up with various random threshold values that can modify the final performance accuracy, right?

Comment: It is not adviseable to use a decision threshold within a model that you are training. Nontheless a decision is adviseable when interpreting your model once deployed to take business interest into account (e.g. diffferent false-positive to false-negative cost)

Comment: Thank you once again Nikolas. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The `predict` method returns an array-like value. Basically, you are comparing every row in the prediction (which are floats, possibly probabilities) to your threshold of 0.3. You can imagine it working like a list comprehension. It will return another array-like structure of boolean values, indicating whether each prediction exceeds 0.3. For your final step you are basically converting this boolean array into an integer array by casting the true/false values. Mathematically, you can think of it working like a step function.

I imagine it'll be easier to comprehend how your code works if you deconstruct it into smaller units. First, check the output of predictions, then check the output of the comparison, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so very much for getting back to me with this response. So, the threshold is merely a decision boundary that we apply in coming up with the target values, right?

Comment: Thanks. So as far as I understand, setting such a threshold is not advisable when it comes to a deep learning model that should intentionally learn the threshold and predict on its own.

Comment: Well, I'm not a ML expert. However, if you have binary labels, you're always going to need a threshold to convert your floats to true/false for metrics comparison. That's why we use activation functions.

Comment: With weights and biases being used to finetune parameters to get better outputs, we end up with a weighted sum which is a value that can be any number. But what we need for this network is for the activations of each neuron to be sub value between 0 and 1. So we pump this weighted sum into an activation function that squishes the real number line into the range between 0 and 1.